Why is the below sentence desribed as "ungrammatical"?

The above screenshot is from Erica Meltzer's "Ultimate Guide to SAT Grammar".
I don't understand why this sentence is ungrammatical:
Born Elaine Potter Richardson in Antigua, Caribbean-American author began her career as a jorunalist.
If we added "the" before "Caribbean-American", would that make the sentence grammatical?

I don't know about 'ungrammatical', but there is no point in mentioning her birth name if the sentence doesn't include her pen name - the name she is known by.

The issue is simply one of whether and how many commas to include. Which isn't really a matter of being "grammatical" amyway - it's the same in speech as in the written form. By convention, there are no pauses or commas in the specified position, so the second option is the "correct" one. It's nothing to do with including a definite article, which is just an optional stylistic choice. But your suggested alternative without her actual name is syntactic nonsense.

@FumbleFingers I know that the test question is about commas, but I wanted to understand what exactly makes the cited sentence incorrect. I don't really see why this is a "syntactic nonsense", that's why I asked if adding, for example, "the" (and not the name) would fix this.

No, it wouldn't. The sentence is about the author who writes as Jamaica Kincaid. If this name isn't mentioned, it seems odd to mention her 'real' name. A reader would think "OK, but what Caribbean-American author are they talking about?"

Born Elaine Potter Richardson in Antigua, Caribbean-American author Jamaica Kincaid began her career as a journalist. Now it works.

It's ungrammatical because the text after the comma does not make a full sentence:

Caribbean-American author began her career as a journalist.

You need some kind of determinant for "Caribbean-American author". You could for example have "The Caribbean-American author began...", or as the question has "Caribbean-American author Jamaica Kinkaid begain..."

The sentence "Born Elaine Potter Richardson in Antigua, Caribbean-American author began her career as a journalist." is ungrammatical because it lacks a subject before the verb "began." The phrase "Caribbean-American author" is meant to describe the person who began her career, but without a determiner (like "the") or a specific name before "Caribbean-American author," the sentence leaves out the subject.
Adding "the" before "Caribbean-American" would indeed make the sentence grammatical:
"Born Elaine Potter Richardson in Antigua, the Caribbean-American author began her career as a journalist."
In this revised sentence, "the Caribbean-American author" serves as the complete subject of the sentence, making it grammatically correct. The article "the" properly introduces "Caribbean-American author" as the subject who began her career.
